# Make docker, registry cache container Use http proxy

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a caching local registry for docker using official `registry:latest` Image. 
I want to make this container use organizations `http proxy` for internet access when trying to pull from docker hub.

any help would be appretiated.

P.S you can follow this [guide](https://blog.docker.com/2015/10/registry-proxy-cache-docker-open-source/) to create a caching local registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of trying different stuff, answering my own question to help others.

`sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /home/myhomedirectory/test:/var/lib/registry -e http_proxy=http://organizationswebproxyaddress:port/ --name registry registry /var/lib/registry/config.yml`

Look at `-e` switch with `-e` switch you can pass in environmental variables to the container. In this case im passing `http_proxy` environmental variable so the container uses my http proxy for accessing the Internet. you can even authenticate if your proxy needs authentication.

Comment: I assumed you had already done this from the line in your original question: "I already tried setting http_proxy inside the container with no luck." Including the commands you were running would have helped debug your problem faster.

Comment: He deleted the line after you pointed it out :D